# How to find the cpu and memory usage of child processes

Tags: shell, centos, process, ps, cpu-usage

`supervisord` is running on CentOS server. If I do

```
ps -e -o %mem,%cpu,cmd | grep supervisord | awk '{memory+=$1;cpu+=$2} END {print memory,cpu}'
```

I get `0 0` just because `supervisord` is just an initialization daemon. It runs four child processes on my server:

```
# pgrep -P $(pgrep supervisord) | wc -l
4
```

How can I find summarized CPU and memory usage of these child processes in one-line-command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code from [happyraul's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147881/117037),

> ```
> pgrep -P $(pgrep supervisord) | xargs ps -o %mem,%cpu,cmd -p | awk '{memory+=$1;cpu+=$2} END {print memory,cpu}'
> ```

will get only one child layer.

If you want to search for all processes that were derived from a main pid, use this code:

```
ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,comm,%cpu,%mem  -u {user name} | {grep PID_PRINCIPAL}
```

The pid of main process is the PGID of child processes.

Answer (score 5):

Given a `pid`,

```
pid=24535
pstree -p $pid | grep -o '([0-9]\+)' | grep -o '[0-9]\+' |\
  xargs ps -o %mem,%cpu,cmd -p | awk '{memory+=$1;cpu+=$2} END {print memory,cpu}'
# 15.5 905.2
```

I had no luck getting the pids of all child processes from pgrep.

Comment: %cpu in ps is, in fact, problematic. It is calculated as `CPU time used divided by the time the process has been running` - that is, historical average of the %CPU usage, not its current value.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `xargs`:

```
pgrep -P $(pgrep supervisord) | xargs ps -o %mem,%cpu,cmd -p | awk '{memory+=$1;cpu+=$2} END {print memory,cpu}'
```